# Is buffer valid when the builder is destroyed?

Tags: c++, serialization, flatbuffers

I'm using flatbuffers for serialisation of objects to transfer over network, question is whether the buffer remains valid after the `FlatBufferBuild` is out of scope, for example:

```
char* GetBuffer(...size_t &size) {
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder fbb;
    flatbuffers::Offset<MyStruct> data = CreateMyStruct(fbb, ...);
    FinishMyStructBuffer(fbb, data);
    size = fbb.GetSize();
    return fbb.GetBufferPointer();
}

size_t size;
char* mybuf = GetBuffer(..., size);
do(mybuf, size);
```

Is my usage of `mybuf` valid memory buffer? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FlatBufferBuilder` class is using a custom class as the underlying array that holds the data. The class itself is called `flatbuffers::vector_downward` and the documentation says:

> This is a minimal replication of std::vector functionality, except growing from higher to lower addresses.

The class follows the principles of [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii), so the destructor is handling the job to release the allocated data.

```
~vector_downward() {
    clear_buffer();
    clear_allocator();
}
```

So basically, you are accessing to a memory that has been de-allocate when leaving the function scope.

Now there are plenty of alternatives to solve this problem. I will personally avoid another argument in a function and create a custom builder. Something like this:

```
struct MyStructBuilder {
    char* GetBuffer(..., size_t &size) {
        flatbuffers::Offset<MyStruct> data = CreateMyStruct(fbb, ...);
        FinishMyStructBuffer(fbb, data);
        size = fbb.GetSize();
        return fbb.GetBufferPointer();
    }
private:
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder fbb;
};

MyStructBuilder builder;
size_t size;
char* mybuf = builder.GetBuffer(..., size);
do(mybuf, size);
```

Or you can use `FlatBufferBuilder::Release`, but you will need to deal with the fact of releasing the memory. It's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of `mybuf` is not valid and it will lead to undefined behaviour as `FlatBufferBuilder` destroys the internal buffer when its destructor is called. I would suggest using `DetachedBuffer` as following:

```
flatbuffers::DetachedBuffer GetBuffer(...) {
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder fbb;
    flatbuffers::Offset<MyStruct> data = CreateMyStruct(fbb, ...);
    FinishMyStructBuffer(fbb, data);
    return fbb.Release();
}

flatbuffers::DetachedBuffer mybuf = GetBuffer(...);
do(mybuf);
```

Note that `DetachedBuffer` would own the underlying buffer memory and would release it once it's destructor is called.